# Use an updated field to update another one

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to do only one update query but I've got some troubles. First, here is what I tried:

```
UPDATE Table set value1 = val, value4  = value2 - (value1 + value3) WHERE Condition
```

My problem is, the value4 seems to use the "non-updated" value of value1. Finaly i used 2 queries but i would like to know if there is a way to do it in one query.

Thanks in advance (and sorry for my English, i'm a french student)

Edit: A little bit more informations, i'm using oracle database and my app use symfony and doctrine queries. Thanks all I will try your solutions.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Added `sql-server` tag based on the accepted answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be database specific, but in SQL Server you can use a variable to make a value available on subsequent fields within the same `UPDATE` statement:

```
DECLARE @value1 AS INT
UPDATE Table 
SET @value1 = value1 = val
  , value4  = value2 - (@value1 + value3) 
WHERE Condition
```

Also...  in your example you could just reference `val` again:

```
UPDATE Table 
SET value1 = val
  , value4  = value2 - (val + value3) 
WHERE Condition
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You need either 2 Update statements or you need to use new value in your query:

```
UPDATE Table
     SET value1 = @val,
         value 4 = value2 - (@val - value3)
WHERE ...
```